# I'd like to make a word list, but I can't choose how to store it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios

I'm making a word list to study English.

There is a prepared word list, and I'll include it in the app.

But how can I include it efficiently?

I heard that there are some solutions like using sqlite or Core Data.

Apple doesn't like using sqlite.

Also, it's difficult to convert word list to Core Data.

Do I have to select one of two solutions, or are there any more cool solutions?

Comment: As a newbie, I wanna know why Apple doesn't like SQLite. Will using SQLite cause some potential problem in an app?

Comment: I always thought Core Data used SQLite as its backing store...

Comment: Apple ship SQLite with the Mac.  They also encourage its use on the iPhone, so they most certainly do like it :)  If you don't want to use the C API for SQLite, check out FMDB.

Comment: Apple doesn't dislike SQLite, I don't know where you got that idea. As Ignacio notes, Core Data most often uses SQLite as the actual data store, and directly accessing a SQLite database is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in a plist, like this question/answer describe: [How to read data structure from .plist file into NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Or you can store the word list in a JSON format (as a text file) and read from there. An added benefit of setting this up is that you would be set up to read word lists from a server.