# MyApp-Info.plist question

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an XCode iPad app and I have a key in my plist of type Array.

1) Does anyone now how to get that array from the plist?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

plist files can be handled natively by the phone's OS.  Try reading up on this answer:

[How to read data structure from .plist file into NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of the app info file by calling `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]`. That gives you the whole plist as an `NSDictionary`, which you can then query via `objectForKey:`.

Or, to get a single key value from the dictionary, you can do this:

```
NSArray *infoArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"myKey"];
```