# How do I read a value of a property list file key into a string for iphone app using Xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, plist

I have a property list file  "someFile.plist" and within the plist I have two rows "row1" and "row2" each with a string value that is either "Y" or "N" - If I want to check the "someFile.plist" file for "row2" to obtain the value of that row and read it into a string in objective c, how would I do that? I am coding for an iphone App using Xcode.

Comment: -1 this question has been asked like a thousand times. You know [Google](http://bit.ly/OJWCmD) right?

Comment: Hi Max - yes I did search for this but didn't find exactly what Anne graciously answered. Good luck trolling :)

Comment: No trolling. Just saying that the second link on the above google search is the exact same [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the `.plist` into a `NSDictionary` like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Loop through the `NSDictionary` using something like:

```
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use a loop if I know what the name of the row is? So, for instance the key name of row 1 of the plist file is named "row 1". Is there a way to code for the specific string value of that key and assign it to a string I can use in my code? I guess I also don't see where you declare "dictionary" in the above. Did you mean to use "dict" in the for loop? thx for the help!

Comment: Oops, `dictionary` should indeed be replaced by `dict`, sorry for the confusion. In case the key is `row 1` you can get the value using `NSString *theValue = [dict objectForKey:@"row 1"];`. I generally use the loop above to see how the `.plist` is read into the dictionary. In case the dictionary is static you can simply hardcode the keys.

Comment: Awesome - that's what I was looking for. I will try that. Looks like it should work like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the value of "row2" to String then it depends if you are having Dictionary type or Array type. In the case of Dictionary type:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pListFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString valueOfRow2 = [dict objectForKey:@"row2"]);
NSLog(@"The value of row2 is %@", valueOfRow2);
```

and in the case of Array:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pListFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
//the indexes of NSArray is counted from 0, not from 1
NSString valueOfRow2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"The value of row2 is %@", valueOfRow2);
```

You can use NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray respectively. It would be more easy to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourPlistFile", ofType: "plist"), let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let value = dict["KeyInYourPlistFile"] as! String
    }
```