# How to read Array from plist iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to read plist which contains array

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>key1</key>
<string>value1</string>
<key>key2</key>
<string>value2</string>
<key>keyarray1</key>
<array>
    <string>keyitem1</string>
    <string>keyitem2</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

when i try to read valueForKey:@"keyarray1", I get null value. 
I tried to read as a string and array nut no use.

My Code

```
NSDictionary * values=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"values.plist"];
NSArray *arrayValues=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[values valueForKey:@"keyarray1"]];
```

Comment: Could you show us your full code that reads the plist?

Comment: I can read the key1 and key2 but cann't read array.

Comment: send a screen shots of ur plist

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read data structure from .plist file into NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First of all Check your plist looks like:

[image]

Now write following lines where you are accessing your plist

**Objective-C:**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Values" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"keyarray1"];
NSLog(@"dictionary = %@ \narray = %@", dictionary, array);
```

Here is the complete screen shot (with log output) of my work window:

[image]

**Swift:**

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.pathForResource("Values", ofType: "plist")!);
let array = dictionary?["arrayKey"] as! NSArray
print("dictionary=",  dictionary, "\narray =",  array)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is too old and I'll just like to add more information for those people encounter this recently.

In my case I created a plist as Array(plist default is Dictionary with key "Root").

[image]

then the xml looks like this:

[image]

On my view controller I initialize directly the Array instead of initializing the Dictionary then get object for key "Root":

[image]

**Note:** I only wanted to add this info since I only see initializing the Dictionary then get object for keys. Hope it will help you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the plist stored? Is it in the app bundle? If so, you probably want to use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values" ofType:@"plist"]` to get the path, instead of hardcoding `@"values.plist"`.

After you have the path down correctly, you can then get the array from the dictionary without any problems, with something like  `[values objectForKey:@"keyarray"]`.

Final note: there is a difference between `objectForKey:` and `valueForKey:`. You're currently using `valueForkey:` which is part of `NSKeyValueCoding`, a protocol that NSDictionary happens to conform to. You should use `objectForKey:` (or syntactic sugar accessors, i.e. `dictionary[@"key"]`) instead, as they are the proper ways of accessing a value from a dictionary.

Comment: I tried to use `objectforkey` but no use.
I do get the count as 0.

Comment: What happens if you `NSLog(@"values: %@", values);` ? Does any thing get printed out, or, do you see "(null)"?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following code?

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary * values=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *arrayValues=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[values valueForKey:@"keyarray1"]];
NSLog(@"arrayValues = %@",arrayValues);
```

I got following output in log:-

```
arrayValues = (
    keyitem1,
    keyitem2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

As in Swift 4 you can use **codable & PropertyListDecoder**

```
func setData() {
  // location of plist file
  if let settingsURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JsonPlist", ofType: "plist") {
    do {
      var settings: MySettings?
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: settingsURL))
      let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
      settings = try decoder.decode(MySettings.self, from: data)
      print("array  is \(settings?.keyarray1 ?? [""])")//prints ["keyitem1", "keyitem2"]
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}

struct MySettings: Codable {
  var keyarray1: [String]?

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    keyarray1 = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .keyarray1)
  }
}
```

For more see this [How to read from a plist with Swift 3 iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910461/how-to-read-from-a-plist-with-swift-3-ios-app/49228400#49228400)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"values.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
NSArray *arr =[dict valueForKey:@"keyarray1"];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to find the path of an item within the app bundle. Don't assume it will be a flat bundle, basically. Also, you shouldn't use `valueForKey:` when accessing values from NSDictionary.

Comment: then what should i use when accessing values from NSDictionary?

Comment: `-objectForKey:`. See my answer to @ram2013 in this very question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269368/162361

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"values.plist"]; or NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values" ofType:@"plist"]; could you explain wrong way to find the path of an item within the app bundle

Comment: Using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` — as your answer does — assumes that the path to the resource will be a flat file one level below the bundle. This might not be the case. At some point in the future, resources might be moved into a Resources/ folder (as it is on Mac), for example. `pathForResource:ofType:` is a much more correct way of getting the path, but, is not what you are using in your answer.