# Unable to do login validations in iOS

Tags: ios

How to do validations for username and password by comparing text entered to the data in plists?

I have created 2 arrays username and password in plist manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read Array from plist iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269126/how-to-read-array-from-plist-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a plist called authentication.plist which has two fields of type string (I know you wrote arrays but couldn't understand why. If you are determined to use them the link posted by Kumar Kl explains how to read them from the plist):

1. username
2. password

You read the plist file into an `NSDictionary` using:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"authentication" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Let's suppose you have the username entered by the user in an `NSString` called `enteredUsername` and the password in an `NSString` called `enteredPassword`.
You could then compare the entered values with the ones in the plist like so:

```
if ([enteredUsername isEqualToString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"username"]])
{
    NSLog(@"Username matches!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Username does not match");
}
if ([enteredPassword isEqualToString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"password"]])
{
    NSLog(@"Password matches!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Password does not match");
}
```