# Using Spreadsheets of Data in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am developing a soccer application in xCode, which will require me to have 300 different "players" in the game, all with various attributes (nation, position, rating, age, etc.). In my code, I create these by creating a "player" object and initializing it with all the parameters. However, the process of creating all 300 players is very tedious and inefficient. Is there a better way to create all the objects, perhaps by pulling the data from a spreadsheet or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `plist` and store data in that file. You can define `Dictionary`  or `Array` there, and read it from there:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Values" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary);
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"keyarray1"];
NSLog(@"array = %@", array);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269126/how-to-read-array-from-plist-ios) is a very good explanation of how `Plists` work.