# How to read from a plist with Swift 3 iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist, swift3

*-Disclaimer-

I'm extremely new to iOS and Swift development, but I'm not particularly new to programming.*

I have a basic `iOS` application with `Swift3` elements in it.
I've created a `plist` file with some entries I want to read and display in my application. (No write access is necessary)

**How can you read a value for a given key for a bundled `plist` file, in Swift3?**

This seems like a really simple question to me, but a bunch of searching is making me question my whole conceptual approach.

Helpful tips would be appreciated.

Comment: see this http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/ and this http://www.learncoredata.com/plist/

Comment: The rebeloper site noted above is a link to a library to handle these things. It might be great, I don't know, but it's certainly a long article describing a process that is far more complicated than this process ought to require.

The second site is a dead link for me on this day.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Same way you have done in Swift 2.3 or lower just syntax is changed.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "plist") {

    //If your plist contain root as Array
    if let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String: Any]] {

    }

    ////If your plist contain root as Dictionary
    if let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any] {

    }
}
```

**Note:** In Swift it is better to use Swift's generic type Array and Dictionary instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

**Edit:** Instead of `NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)` and `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` we can also use [`PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/propertylistserialization/1409678-propertylist) to read data from `plist` file.

```
if let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fileName", withExtension: "plist"),
   let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
       if let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String: Any]] { // [String: Any] which ever it is 
            print(result)
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found a lot of examples for Swift != 3. I'm concerned about adopting Swift as I've also heard it's had two fairly major redecorations in its very short life.

Comment: @Doc   

It is worth noting that some plists are pre-defined.  Most notably, info.plist :  

```static let BASE_URL  = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["MY_BASE_URL"] as! String```

Comment: To emphasize the very good point by @Dilapidus, the correct/accepted answer to this question should be based on `Bundle.main.infoDictionary` ... it's right there waiting for you.  No need for more code.

Answer (score 12):

As Swift 4 introduces **Codable**

**Step 1: Load the Plist File from bundle.**

**Step 2: Use PropertyListDecoder for the decoding of property list values into semantic `Decodable` types.**

**Step 3: Create Codable Struct**

*Complete code -*

```
 func setData() {
        // location of plist file
        if let settingsURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JsonPlist", ofType: "plist") {

            do {
                var settings: MySettings?
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: settingsURL))
                    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
                settings = try decoder.decode(MySettings.self, from: data)
                    print("toolString is \(settings?.toolString ?? "")")
                print("DeviceDictionary is \(settings?.deviceDictionary?.phone ?? "")")
                print("RootPartArray is \(settings?.RootPartArray ?? [""])")

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MySettings: Codable {
    var toolString: String?
    var deviceDictionary: DeviceDictionary?
    var RootPartArray: [String]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case toolString = "ToolString"
        case deviceDictionary = "DeviceDictionary"
        case RootPartArray
    }

    struct DeviceDictionary: Codable {
        var phone: String?
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .phone)
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        toolString = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .toolString)
        deviceDictionary = try values.decodeIfPresent(DeviceDictionary.self, forKey: .deviceDictionary)
        RootPartArray = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .RootPartArray)

    }
}
```

Sample Plist file -> https://gist.github.com/janeshsutharios/4b0fb0e3edeff961d3e1f2829eb518db

Comment: I think It has better performance when considered with saving it to NSDictionary or Dictionary right?

Comment: Codable is optimal by Apple

Answer (score 3):

Here is example how to get BundleID from Info plist:

```
var appBundleID = "Unknown Bundle ID"    
if let bundleDict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary, 
   let bundleID = bundleDict[kCFBundleIdentifierKey as String] as? String {
       appBundleID = bundleID
   }
```

The same way you may easily access any key. This approach is good for many-target projects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **Swift 3** implementation, based on [Nirav D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39910534):

```
    /// Read Plist File.
    ///
    /// - Parameter fileURL: file URL.
    /// - Returns: return plist content.
    func ReadPlist(_ fileURL: URL) -> [String: Any]? {
        guard fileURL.pathExtension == FileExtension.plist, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any] else {
            return nil
        }
        print(result)
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion. Would you please walk me through how this is different from Nirav D's answer? I like that you have exception handling involved. Is that basically it?

Comment: @JamesTSnell Thank you for your question. The two answers are basically the same.I just abstracted his answer as a function for calling easily.
Nirav D's answer didn't handle the exception or something wrong.
So in my function, if some bad things happened will return nil. Hope for help.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0, Following code directly targeting to key. Where as **dict** object will give everything which will be there in your plist file.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourPlistFile", ofType: "plist"), let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let value = dict["KeyInYourPlistFile"] as! String
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In AppDelegate File**

```
var bundlePath:String!
    var documentPath:String!
    var plistDocumentPath:URL!
    let fileManager = FileManager()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Team", ofType: "plist")

        documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first

        plistDocumentPath = URL.init(string: documentPath)?.appendingPathComponent("Team.plist")
        print(plistDocumentPath.path)

        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: plistDocumentPath.path){

            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath, toPath: plistDocumentPath.path)
            } catch  {
                print("error Occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }


        return true
    }
```

**In ViewController**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var TeamTable: UITableView!
    var appDelegate:AppDelegate!
    var arrayForContacts:[[String:Any]]! // array object


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if appDelegate.fileManager.fileExists(atPath: appDelegate.plistDocumentPath.path){
            arrayForContacts = []
            if let contentOfPlist = NSArray.init(contentsOfFile: appDelegate.plistDocumentPath.path ){
                arrayForContacts = contentOfPlist as! [[String:Any]]
                TeamTable.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also read value directly from your plist file by simply

```
let value = Bundle.init(for: AppDelegate.self).infoDictionary?["your plist key name"] as? Any
```