# NSDictionary init(contentsOfFile:) is deprecated so now what?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, plist, ios11

Recently (as of iOS 11), `init(contentsOfFile:)` in `NSDictionary` became deprecated.

[image]

I wanted to be a forward-thinking citizen, so I looked for another way to load a property list (plist) into a `NSDictionary` type. The only thing I could find was `PropertyListSerialization` but it is cumbersome comparatively.

This is what I came up with to show the difference:

```
func dealWithFakeConf(atPath path:String) {
    // So easy!
    let myD:Dictionary<String,Any> = NSDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    let l = myD["location"] as? String ?? "BAD_STRING"
    let q = myD["quantity"] as! Int
    print("location = \(l)")
    print("quantity = \(q.description)")

    // Old is new again?!
    guard let rawData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path) else {
        fatalError("Sumpin done gone wrong!")
    }
    var format = PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml
    let data = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:rawData, options:[.mutableContainers], format:&format)
    guard let realData = data as? Dictionary<String,Any> else {
        fatalError("OMG! Now what?")
    }
    locationLabel.text = realData["location"] as? String ?? "BAD_STRING"
    let qty:Int? = realData["quantity"] as? Int
    quantityLabel.text = qty?.description
}
```

I noticed that [this answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910461/how-to-read-from-a-plist-with-swift-3-ios-app/39910534#39910534) has golfed the use of `PropertyListSerialization` down to less code that what I came up with, but that is not obvious when reading [Apple's 7 year old docs *Property List Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html). And that example is **still** 3 indentations deep.

Am I missing a replacement convenience initializer somewhere else? Is this what we do now to load a plist into a Dictionary?

Comment: It's deprecated as of iOS 11, not iOS 10.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I have fixed tag & text to reflect your confident comment.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a fair comparison.

Actually the literal *translation* of

```
let myD = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String : Any]
```

is

```
let rawData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
let realData = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: rawData, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
```

In both cases the code crashes if something goes wrong.

However in both cases you should do proper error handling.

Comment: Thanks for golfing the code down. I appreciate that. I can skip the FileManager step. But if I'm doing the same thing in both cases (not handling error conditions), then that **is** a fair comparison, right?