# want to fetch data from array of dictionary from plist in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, plist

I am new to iPhone,as per requirement I have to select a single question from list of question in the tableview,and want to show that question in the next new view.so I send my row value to new Xib file as the time of creation.

I stored my question-ans in plist as a array of dictionary format.I can fetch the array from Plist,but unable to fetch dictionary data..I made my custom class to store question-Answer.but at the new get only the last question that is stored in the plist.
Please help me.thank u..

Here I am attaching my code `tableView.m,newView.m` and `customClass.m`..

**tableView.m**

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            NSLog(@" index row value:%d",indexPath.row);
           NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
            questionViewController *viewController1 =
            [[questionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"questionViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            viewController1.rowValue=row;
                self.viewController = viewController1;
            [self.viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Ques Details"];


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
    }
```

in The new Xib File,In ViewDidLoadFunction

**newView.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      //rowValue tells me which row is selected
        [self firstView:rowValue];

    }
    -(void)firstView: (NSInteger)indexNumber{
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Qus_ans" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *rawElementsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        NSDictionary *eachElement;
     //overlap the data here   
     for (eachElement in rawElementsArray)
        {
           element = [[Question alloc] initWithDictionary:eachElement];}
   //get only last question in the plist
   questionLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",element.ques];

     }
    element is my Custom class object.This is my custom class:
    Question.m

    - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {

        self = [[Question alloc] init];
        if (self) {

            self.ques = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"question"];
            self.ans = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"answer"];

            [self data];
        }
        return self;
    }

    Here element.ques is overlapped with the last value.
    How I get proper question without using the forLoop...
```

This is my plist format

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>question</key>
        <string>Approximately how much does the human brain weigh?</string>
        <key>answer</key>
        <string>Three pounds</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>question</key>
        <string>The brain has this number of The brain has this number of nerve cells?</string>
        <key>answer</key>
        <string>1 to 100 billion</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Please format your question. It is very hard to read.

Comment: thats why I mentioned previously that I am new to iPhone,but I think i mentioned clearly purpose of the every function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray

Comment: this link help. before post search stackoverflow weather this question is available or not

Comment: thank You sir.But I want something like that-I am selecting the particular data  from didSelectRowAtIndexPath,and want to fetch that  particular row number dictionaries' key value from array of dictionaries from the plist.through for loop I can fetch whole data of the plist,but how I stored that particular row key from the dictionary.

Comment: help needed.thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not entirely sure I undestand your problem, but if you are trying to get rid of your for loop (which I guess is the case), you could simply write

```
NSArray *rawElementsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
NSDictionary * dic = rawElementsArray objectAtIndex:rowNumber];
```

Comment: thank you  Sir.It is working.I made a mistake in my code.i wrote  NSString *versionString = [rawElementsArray objectAtIndex:indexNumber];  this line in my code.and that goes wrong for every time.