# Reading .plist data into a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm having problems reading XML data in a plist file into a dictionary. The problems include the plist not being recognised as part of the bundle despite the correct options to add it to the project being checked on import.

I'm looking for a simple way to read the data when the program starts and thereafter have it easily available via methods that access the array. The data does not need to be rewritten or changed so a single transfer is all that is required for the program to function.

Here is an example of the data structure of the .plist (with fewer records than the actual file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>19” HD Monitor</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <integer>11999</integer>
        <key>ProdId</key>
        <integer>123</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>4GB RAM Module</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <integer>2995</integer>
        <key>ProdId</key>
        <integer>456</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Samsung 256GB SSD</string>
        <key>Price</key>
        <integer>11250</integer>
        <key>ProdId</key>
        <integer>789</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

The data consists of a product name (String), its price in pence or cents (Int) and a unique product ID (Int). The key names of these are 'Name', 'Price' and 'ProdID' respectively.

Here's the code I'm using to read the data in. I'm using a simple command line program to isolate this operation in a simple form with a test to see if the data has been stored and retrieved from the dictionary. The data operations will be provided in a class:

```
//
//  Datadump.swift
//  PListTester
//
//  Created by Kwangle on 30/11/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 KwangCo All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation


class Datadump {


    //declare container array
    var dictArray: Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>

    //reads data when class is constructed
    init () {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: Datadump.self)
        //gets file location of 'Products.plist' from bundle
        let fileLocation = bundle.pathForResource("Hardware", ofType: "plist")

        //creates NSArray from contents of 'Hardware.plist'
        let productArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: fileLocation!)
        //creates dictionary array from NSArray via force conversion
        dictArray = productArray as! Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>

        for (var i = 0; i < dictArray.count; i++){
            dictArray.append(productArray!.objectAtIndex(i) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        }
    }

//reads price value of matching ProdID  
        func priceFromID(pId: Int) -> Int{
            var price = 0
            //iterate through array until relevant product is found
            for dict in dictArray{
                //reads 'ProdId' key and compares it to pId function argument
                if dict["ProdId"] as! Int == pId{
                    //if product ID is found price is set to its value
                    price = dict["Price"] as! Int
                    break
                }
            }

        return price;

    }

}//end class
```

The Main method just creates an instance of the DataDump class and runs the priceFromID method with a value that matches a ProdId:

```
//
//  main.swift
//  PListTester
//
//  Created by Kwangle on 29/11/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 KwangCo All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

//creates instance of Datadump class
var myData = Datadump ()

//queries data
print (myData.priceFromID(123) )
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

This relates to the line:

```
let productArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: fileLocation!)
```

I'm also getting the error code:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Kw

Comment: Add `print(fileLocation) right below the line that sets the `fileLocation`. I assume this in nil. Is the name of the file correct?

Comment: Yes, that's returning nil.

Comment: Ist the name of the file `Hardware.plist`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `NSBundle(forClass: Datadump.self)` rather than the usual `NSBundle.mainBundle()` ?

Comment: Yes the filename is correct, but the the checkbox that indicates that the .plist file's target membership is 'PListTester' is unchecked and cannot be changed for some reason. I've tried re-importing the file but this does not change.

Comment: First try to change the name into `hardware.plist`. If that doesn't work, replace the line with this: `let fileLocation = bundle.pathForResource("Hardware.plist", ofType: "")`.

Comment: @vadian: A kludge I put in in an attempt to rectify the problem. removing the forClass: Datadump.self argument makes no difference.

Comment: @dasdom: Changed the filename and references manually and tried the "Hardware.plist" and ofType: ""  - no change

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Is the plist file listed in Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources? If not try to add the file there. Apart from the issue I recommend to use the URL related API of `NSBundle`/`NSArray`

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot where the file is in the project navigator?

Comment: Link to image of XCode screen. Note that the file cannot be checked: http://i.imgur.com/0K945du.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to load the contents into an array. You want a dictionary.

Look here;

[How to read data structure from .plist file into NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Comment: The `fileLocation` is nil. First he/she has to solve this problem. :)]